# Session bean creation error on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, stateless-session-bean

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, I tried to create a stateless session bean but I'm getting an error that says it cannot resolve @Stateless. Where I'm I going something wrong?

Comment: What dependencies did you add? Provide implementation to understand the problem better.

Comment: You're probably not adding the neccesary dependencies

Comment: ` <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.wasdev.maven.tools.targets</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-target</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>i1.test.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>TestAppEJB</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> `